# How can I end my program when one of players win?

Tags: java, methods

I have here a simple battleship game, where 2 player enters cords for their ships and then they shoot each other. How can I stop the program, when one of them scores 5 successful hits?
Siatka A is where player A puts his ships and siatka B where B puts his.

```
public static int shotA(boolean enemy[][], boolean mine[][]){
    Scanner shot = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = Integer.parseInt(shot.nextLine());
    int y = Integer.parseInt(shot.nextLine());
    if (enemy[x][y]==true){
        System.out.println("Trafiony");
        System.out.println("Jeszcze raz strzelasz");
        shotA(enemy, mine);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Pudło");
        System.out.println("Teraz gracz B");
        shotB(mine, enemy);
    }
    return ;
}

public static int shotB(boolean enemy[][], boolean mine[][]){
    Scanner shot = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = Integer.parseInt(shot.nextLine());
    int y = Integer.parseInt(shot.nextLine());
    
    if (enemy[x][y]==true){
        
        System.out.println("Trafiony");
        System.out.println("Jeszcze raz strzelasz");
        shotB(enemy, mine);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Pudło");
        System.out.println("Teraz gracz A");
        shotB(mine, enemy);
    }
    return ;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[][] siatkaA = new boolean[10][10];
    boolean[][] siatkaB = new boolean[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < siatkaA.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < siatkaA[0].length; j++) {
            siatkaA[i][j]=false;
            siatkaB[i][j]=false;
        }
    }
    
    Scanner wsp = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Podaj wspołrzędne 5 statków graczu A(wartości 0-9, pisane po przecinku");
    String statkiA=wsp.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Podaj wspołrzędne 5 statków graczu B(wartości 0-9, pisane po przecinku");
    String statkiB=wsp.nextLine();
    String[] wspA= statkiA.split(",");
    String[] wspB= statkiB.split(",");
    int first=0;
    int second=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < wspA.length; i+=2) {
        first=Integer.parseInt(wspA[i]);
        second=Integer.parseInt(wspA[i+1]);
        siatkaA[first][second]=true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < wspB.length; i+=2) {
        first=Integer.parseInt(wspB[i]);
        second=Integer.parseInt(wspB[i+1]);
        siatkaB[first][second]=true;
    }
    
    
    System.out.println("Zaczyna gracz A:");
    shotA(siatkaB, siatkaA);
```

I am doing this simple code for training, but i am stuck at that part and asking for some help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to add two counter variables, one for each player (playerA and playerB) so when a shot is successful, add one to the counter variable. When a counter variable is equal to 5, you would set a boolean variable to true and write an if statement like if the boolean flag is true then end the game.

Comment: Something like this for example?
`int vicA=0;
        if (enemy[x][y]==true){
            System.out.println("Trafiony");
            System.out.println("Jeszcze raz strzelasz");
            vicA++;
            shotA(enemy, mine);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Pudło");
            System.out.println("Teraz gracz B");
            shotB(mine, enemy);
        }
        return vicA;`
Inside method of course

Comment: Yes and then use that to control the boolean flag variable that will end the game

Comment: `boolean end=false
if (vicA==5){
end =true;
}`
Something like this, put i don't know where to put it in my code. And what statement use to terminate the program

Comment: To exit a Java programme without throwing an error you can either allow the `main` method to exit, i.e allow it to reach the end, or you could use the `exit` method of the `System` class